# Areas not showing in TFS sprint burndown report

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, scrum, burndowncharts

Using TFS 2010 & Visual Studio 2013 team explorer.

I've created a new TFS project and I've set up a couple Iterations and Areas.

The iterations are as follows:

```
Current
   Sprint 1
Sprint 2
Sprint 3
Sprint 4
Backlog
```

The active sprint will always be under Current so we don't have to modify 'current sprint' queries.

The Areas are as follows:

```
Project 1
Project 2
```

There are a bunch of Product Backlog Items (PBIs) that are committed under Sprint 1. Each of these have some child tasks.

From what I can tell everything seems to be set up correctly e.g. most PBIs have an assigned effort, Area, & Iteration. The Tasks have been assigned Remaining work & Area...

When I go to look at the sprint burndown SSRS report; I select an Iteration from the Iteration combo-box (which is populated correctly), however, when I go to select an Area from the Area combo-box, there are no items to select. I can't run the report unless I've specified both an Iteration and an Area.

How do I get the Areas that I've defined to appear?
Please help.

Comment: Note: TFS 2010 drops out of support in a couple of months. You should upgrade to a more supported version.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the cube has not been processing correctly. You may need to give it a kick.

If you log onto the TFS server and you to the reporting tab in the TFS admin console you can reprocess it.

Note: Do that in off hours as it can take some time.